# How to properly change UI theme?

Tags: android, android-theme

I want a dark colored theme.

I changed the following in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
```

and I also tried many other strings which either don't compile or cause the same crash.
Android monitor shows:

```
08-11 20:07:00.938 29773-29773/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-11 20:07:00.956 29773-29773/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-11 20:07:01.122 29773-29773/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-11 20:07:01.283 29773-29805/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
08-11 20:07:01.457 29773-29805/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-11 20:07:01.457 29773-29805/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-11 20:07:01.457 29773-29805/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-11 20:07:01.457 29773-29805/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
08-11 20:07:01.459 29773-29805/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaa4b1920: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-11 20:07:01.461 29773-29805/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa4b1920: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9e4aa9f0)

                                                                                      [ 08-11 20:07:01.479 29773:29805 D/         ]
                                                                                      SurfaceInterface::setAsyncMode: set async mode 1
08-11 20:07:01.493 29773-29805/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa4b1920: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9e4aa9f0)
```

And the 'run' console shows:

```
08/11 22:01:07: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.timothyswan.myapplication/com.example.timothyswan.myapplication.InspirationBasic" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 6973 on device emulator-5554
Application terminated.
```

Comment: That's not the actual crash logs of the application

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/theming-with-appcompat-1a292b754b35

Answer (score 1):

The theme of an `AppCompatActivity` (not `Activity`) must be an descendant of an `Theme.AppCompat`.

So check if your activity extends `AppCompatActivity` or not.
If so, change it extends `Activity`, or make your own theme which inherits from `Theme.AppCompat` and apply to your activity